# Import Error : cannot import register

Tags: django, django-registration

Getting Import error while trying to run localhost from my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import admin
from mainapp.feeds import LatestReports, CityIdFeed, CitySlugFeed, WardIdFeed, WardSlugFeed,LatestUpdatesByReport
from mainapp.models import City
from social_auth.views import auth as social_auth
from social_auth.views import disconnect as social_disconnect
#Error at this line
from registration.views import register

from mainapp.forms import FMSNewRegistrationForm,FMSAuthenticationForm
from mainapp.views.account import SUPPORTED_SOCIAL_PROVIDERS
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from mainapp.views.mobile import open311v2
import mainapp.views.cities as cities
```

Traceback:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name register
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name register
Exception Location: /home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/fixmystreet/../fixmystreet/urls.py in <module>, line 9
Python Executable:  /home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/fixmystreet',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sourabh/Django/fixmystreet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Thu, 22 Aug 2013 09:34:40 -0500
```

Comment: :) while voting down please consider to mention what's not clear in problem ?

Comment: Are you using [`django-registration`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration)?

Comment: what have you tried? where does register live? what does your python path look like?

Comment: yes i m using django-registration

Comment: @RickyA python path is there in traceback. i m working i a virtualenv

Comment: There is not such `register` view in [django registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/views.py?at=default), so perhaps that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Also check if you have `registration.py` somewhere on the python path.

Comment: i have rechecked that i have indeed installed django-registration so there is no way . import line should give error

Comment: did you include 'registration' in your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: i am trying to work on : https://github.com/visiblegovernment/django-fixmystreet/wiki/Installation
it seems it used some older version of django-registration . is there any way i can get older version of django-registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs you see that register is something that used to exist and was deprecated in the last version. From the [documentation](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade.html?highlight=deprecated):

> The 1.0 release of django-registration represents a **complete rewrite
>   of the previous codebase**, and introduces several new features which
>   [...]

You either downgrade to django-registration v0.8 (where registration.views.register still exists) or learn how to implement the changes to fit the newest version